# Prevent reopening of same document when updating of fields in word document

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I tried to update all the linked charts by updating the fields in the word document, since the charts all belong to the same excel doc, it causes the same excel doc to be reopened over and over again. Is there a way to detect that is the same excel doc and only open once?

```
Sub UpdateDocument()

    Dim WordApplication As Word.Application
    Dim WordDoc As Word.Document
    Dim updateLinks As Boolean
    Dim Filepath As String

    Filepath = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Cells.Value

    Set WordApplication = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    'capture the original value
    updateLinks = WordApplication.Options.UpdateLinksAtOpen

    'temporarily disable
    WordApplication.Options.UpdateLinksAtOpen = False

    Set WordDoc = WordApplication.Documents.Open(Filepath)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    WordDoc.Fields.Update
    WordDoc.Save
    WordDoc.Close

    '## reset the previous value and Quit the Word Application
    WordApplication.Options.UpdateLinksAtOpen = updateLinks             '
    WordApplication.Quit

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This example is unclear. The actual routine gets a Word document path from an Excel spreadsheet at cell B1, explicitly opens that document, updates tables, and then explicitly closes the document. Based on that alone, of course it's going to open and close a document multiple times.

What we're not seeing is the loop that calls UpdateDocument. It depends on how that calling loop is designed. Without seeing that, a guess would be move CreateObject outside of UpdateDocument. Have UpdateDocument open the document but not close it. Close the all Word documents after the looping is done. If the file is opened, it will update when called again.